# Как сделать подобный слайдер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, slider

Из готовых решений что-то у меня не получается найти. А вообще было бы лучше своим кодом сделать. (А если подскажете, как это сделать используя vue.js было бы вообще круто).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Точно такой-же есть [в MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html), можете или от-туда его приклеить, или разобрать по запчастям и воспроизвести уже свой.

Comment: это не vue : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dmEWZp?editors=0110, это vue : https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/?ref=madewithvuejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую **vue-carousel-3d**

Устанавливается командой:

```
npm install -S vue-carousel-3d
```

Comment: Для таких "ответов" есть комментарии вопроса.

Comment: @Visman, нет, это ответ: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1639/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, это не ответ, а отсылка к гуглю, о чем прямо написано во второй строке.

Comment: @Visman, последняя строка ответа - команда для установки библиотеки (npm-пакета) `vue-carousel-3d`. Вторая строка не важна.

Comment: @Visman тоже флагнул и тоже получил отказ. В принципе, если ответ чуть переработать, то он сгодится как ответ (хотя и плохой).